# Value Error : Do not recognize join method Inner

Tags: python, pandas, join, jupyter-notebook, inner-join

I have two Datasets on which I'm working on:

I have stored a data frame in a variable `'corona_data'` & `shape of corona_data = (187,1)`

The other dataset is `Happiness_report`, whose shape is: `(156,4)`

Therefore I wanted to join them,

```
data = corona_data.join(happiness_report,how="Inner")
data.head()
```

After this I'm getting this error

```
Value Error : do not recognize join method Inner
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct method is `inner` not `Inner`. It is case-sensitive.

`data = corona_data.join(happiness_report,how="inner")`

See the documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html